# Why are there fewer ospreys in upper New England?

Tags: ornithology

I have a book by the Audubon Society on building bird houses. In this book the chapter on ospreys shows their breeding range to include Canada and then a pocket around the Connecticut and New York coasts, but no upper New England (Massachusetts, New Hampshire and Maine).

This corresponds to my own experience. I have seen a lot of Osprey nests in Connecticut, but they seem much rarer in Massachusetts and New Hampshire. Why is this?

If the answer was that they prefer a warmer climate, then it makes no sense because they have a widespread breeding range in parts of Canada that are colder than New England.